# Как отличить два роута?

Tags: node.js, http, express, nestjs, fastify

У меня есть два роута
http://example.com/api/test/:id
http://example.com/api/test/another

И когда я пытаюсь достучаться до второго, срабатывает первый и считывает слово another как id
Подскажите пожалуйста как устранить конфликт?

Comment: Поменять порядок регистрации местами?

Comment: Да, вы правы. Поставил без параметра выше и всё заработало)

Comment: Отлично, напишите ответом свое решение